# Sketching $|\sqrt{x}-5|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to sketch $|\sqrt{x}-5|$. Now I know what it is going to look like using basic graphing tools.

My question is, is there an intuitive way to figure out what the graph looks like without making a table of values or using technology to see what the graph looks like?

I know $\sqrt{x}-5$ shifts the graph down five units, but I don't understand why the absolute value flips the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything above $x = 25$, $\sqrt{x} - 5$ will be positive, and the absolute value bars are redundant. So, $|\sqrt{x} - 5| = \sqrt{x} - 5$.
$$$$
However, anything below $x = 25$, $\sqrt{x} - 5$ will be negative, and the absolute value bars will flip the sign. So, $|\sqrt{x} - 5| = -\sqrt{x} + 5$

Answer (score 0):

The absolute value is multiplying by -1 whenever the function is negative.  Multiplying by -1 reflects the graph across the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

If $x \geq 0$, $|x|=x$, that is if a number is nonnegative, its absolute value remains the same.

However, if $x<0$, $|x|=-x$, hence if a number is negative, $|x|$ flips the graph.